# SharePoint Designer Workflow Creating New Document Sets

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-set

**Scenario**: We have a document library with document sets configured with some default documents in them.  When creating a new Document Set normally, it adds the default documents just fine.  We have a SharePoint Designer workflow on another list that runs when new items are added to that list.  The SPD workflow adds a new Document Set to the document library.

**Issue**:  When the SPD workflow creates the new Document Set in the document library, it does not include the default documents for the Document Set.

Any ideas on how to get a SPD Workflow to create the Document Set with the default documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a workflow that fires on the addition of a document set, and creates the default documents in the current document set.

Comment: Ended up going another route entirely, but your suggestion would work.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnChapman Could you please provide your solution [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90166/workflow-creates-document-set-but-not-its-documents)?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an instance of the document set manually are the default documents created? If so, are you using a  2010 or 2013 workflow. The SharePoint 2013 workflows are brain-dead with respect to Document Sets. Switch to a 2010 workflow and try it there.. The 2013 workflow just created folders..  Do it the right way  -- and use the right workflow. A folder in which you have created the default documents will not have the metadata synchronization features that come with real document sets. Get SharePoint explorer and see what is really going on -- my guess is that you're getting a simple folder rather than a document set ( betcha don't have a landing page...