# Workflow creates document set, but not its documents

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, document-set

I'm creating a workflow that will create a new instance of a document set in my document library. This step implemented like this:
[image: Workflow Creation Process]
[image: Workflow Creation Process]

Creating the document set manually (using the SharePoint website) works fine: All documents specified as default content get generated. However, when I create the document set in the same document library using the workflow (above), the document set itself gets generated, but not the default documents specified for this content type.

**Results:**

*GUI Creation*

[image: GUI Creation]

*Workflow Creation*

[image: Workflow Creation]

Comment: Without seing your code it is hard to see where is goes wrong. Also any ULS-log entries is very helpful

Comment: @RobertLindgren There's no code. Only the designed workflow (edited the question). I'll ask my domain admin for the log files.

Comment: Having the same issue creating a document set manually in SP2010. Might be a problem with one of the default documents.